# Полный путь до файла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как получить полный путь до локального фала в JavaScript? Делаю так:

```
 <input type='file' id='file-chooser' />
 ...
 uploader = document.getElementById("file-chooser");
 file = uploader.value
```

В переменной `file` находится только имя, а мне нужен полный путь.

Пояснение к ответу.

Необходимо было делать так

```
 <input type='file' id='file-chooser' />
 ...
 uploader = document.getElementById("file-chooser");
 file = uploader.files[0]
```

И передавать не путь, а сам объект `file`.

Comment: Вообще, разные браузеры в этом случае возвращают разные значения. В FireFox, Opera, IE здесь возвращают именно полное имя файла, а Safari и Chrome - имя.

Comment: Не совсем так. FF возвращает только имя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ввиду политики безопастности вам не дадут полный путь. Да и незачем вам его знать. Зачем ?
Используйте File, FileReader и прочие классы.

Что бы получить объект типа File нужно делать:

```
var file = document.getElementById("file-chooser").files[0];
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.onload = (function(aFile) {
   return function(e) {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="images" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', aFile.name, '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('thumbs').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
})(f);
fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

писалось на коленке так что проверьте синтаксис и т.д )

Comment: Мне надо отправить файл, те передать ссылку на него. Мне не нужно загружать его на сайт. Я должен получить его путь, и передать этот путь другому сервису.

Comment: Тот, другой сервис, на том же компьютере работает? Боюсь, ничего у вас не выйдет в XXI веке.

Comment: Нет, на другом. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @shurik Здесь случаем не HTML5-ый используется?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас задача - закачать файл на сторонний сервис, настройте action формы на скрипт закачки того сервиса. А чтобы не было перехода, грузите файл через скрытый фрейм. Я правильно понял задачу?

Comment: В общем да. Но! Там нет как таковой загрузки. Я вызываю метод api через запрос, в котором передаю путь до файла на локальной машине.